# Should I list all the public IPs for cross-region communication in Cassandra?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

Let's say, I have three data centers using Ec2MultiRegionSnitch.

Public IP of data center A is 50.34.16.33, data center B is 60.247.70.52, and data center C is 52.95.110.54.

Now, should I set the seeds in the cassandra.yaml file like the following?

`seeds: 50.34.16.33, 60.247.70.52, 52.95.110.54`

I came across the following note.

> Note: Do not make all nodes seeds

Does this mean I should set only the two public IPs and not all of them?

`seeds: 50.34.16.33, 60.247.70.52`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt make all nodes seeds but having a seed in every DC is nice.

The assumption is you have more nodes than just 1 in each DC.

For example given 3 DCs and 5 nodes in each DC my seed list would be 2-3 nodes in the same DC and 1 in each of the others. And as I add nodes into DCs the number of seeds would stay the same.